# check_mk error in check_mk.py file

Tags: nagios, check-mk

Could someone please tell me why I am getting following error?

```
OMD[site-name]:~/etc/nagios/conf.d$ check_mk -O

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/omd/sites/site-name/share/check_mk/modules/check_mk.py", line 4560, in <module>
    read_config_files()
  File "/omd/sites/site-name/share/check_mk/modules/check_mk.py", line 4358, in read_config_files
    read_all_autochecks()
  File "/omd/sites/site-name/share/check_mk/modules/check_mk.py", line 4507, in read_all_autochecks
    for (host, ct, it, par) in autochecks ]
  File "/omd/sites/site-name/share/check_mk/modules/check_mk.py", line 4416, in compute_check_parameters
    def_levels_varname = check_info[checktype].get("default_levels_variable")
KeyError: 'linux.version'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this occurs in check_info it would seem you have installed a custom check plugin which is broken.